# Sentencias con operaciones de indice de arreglo en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, algoritmos

El siguiente codigo lo obtuve de un libro:

```
queen = [0 for c in range(8)]        #Row o f queen i n column c
rfree = [True for r in range(8)]     #Row rfree
du = [True for i in range(15)]       #Diagonal i = c + 7 − r
dd = [True for i in range(15)]       #Diagonal i = c + rfree

def solve(c):
    global solutions

    if c == 8:
        solutions += 1 
        print(solutions, end = ": ")
        for r in range(8):
            print (queen[r] + 1 ,end = " " if r<7 else "\n")
    else:       
        for r in range(8):
            if rfree[r] and dd[c + r] and du[ c+7-r]:
                queen[c] = r
                rfree[r] = dd[ c+r ] = du[ c+7-r ] = False
                solve(c+1)
                rfree[r] = dd[ c+r ] = du[ c+7-r ] = True
solutions = 0
solve(0)
print()
print(solutions, "solutions")
```

No entiendo que es lo que esta sucediendo en la linea 14 del codigo y todo lo siguiente a esta linea. En el libro decia que dd es una diagonal desde A1 hasta H8 y du es una diagonal desde H1 hasta A8. No puedo entender lo que sucede en sentencias como du[ c+7-r] = False

Answer (score 5):

## El problema

Lo primero, enunciar el problema para quien no lo conozca. Se trata de encontrar todas las formas posibles de colocar 8 reinas en un tablero de ajedrez de modo que ninguna de ellas amenace a ninguna otra.

Una reina amenaza a otra si está en su misma fila, o columna o en cualquiera de las diagonales que se originan en esa reina:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Consideraciones iniciales

Ya que si están en la misma columna se amenazarían, y tenemos que colocar 8 reinas y un tablero de ajedrez es de 8x8, esto implica que cada reina ha de estar en una columna diferente (y por el mismo razonamiento también ha de estar en una fila diferente).

Así pues, para representar una solución al juego (o un intento de solución mientras verificamos si es o no es válida) basta con almacenar un vector de 8 números, comprendidos entre 0 y 7. El elemento `[0]` de ese vector indicaría en qué fila se halla la reina que está en la columna 0, el elemento `[1]` indicaría en qué fila se halla la reina que está en la columna 1, y así sucesivamente.

Si el vector vale `[1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 0, 6, 4]` estaría representando la siguiente disposición:

[image: Solucion]

Observa que, ya que no puede haber dos reinas en la misma fila, todos los números de ese vector han de ser diferentes entre sí.

## El algoritmo

El algoritmo consiste en ir colocando una a una las reinas, es decir, ir asignando números de 0 a 7 a cada elementos del vector anterior, comenzando por el elemento `[0]`, de modo que no se repita un elemento ya asignado y además *se verifique que no hay dos reinas en diagonal*.

Esta puede ser la parte más compleja. Si una posición `[c]` del vector contiene el valor `n` (indicando que hay una reina en la columna `c`, fila `n`), entonces la posición `[c+1]` no puede contener ni el valor `n-1` ni  el `n+1`, pues eso colocaría otra reina en diagonal con la anterior. La posición `[c+2]` no puede contener ni `n-2` ni `n+2`, pues eso colocaría otra reina en diagonal con la que ya estaba en `[c]`, etc.  En general, la posición `[c+j]` del vector tiene prohibidos los números `n-j` y `n+j`.

Un ejemplo ayuda a entenderlo mejor. Observa la solución anterior, y en concreto la posición `[1]` del vector, que vale 3 indicando que hay una reina en la columna 1, fila 3. Eso amenaza a las posiciones siguientes del vector, siguiendo la diagonal. La siguiente posición `[2]` no podría usar ni 2 ni 4. La siguiente `[3]`, ni 1 ni 5. La siguiente `[4]` ni el 0 ni el 6. La `[5]` no podría usar ni el -1 ni el 7 (el -1 no importa, no podía usarlo de todas formas pues sólo se admiten cifras del 0 al 7). Las posiciones `[6]` y `[7]` no se ven afectadas ya por esta reina, que les estaría prohibiendo usar los números -2,8 y -3,9 respectivamente. Números que de todas formas ya no se podían usar.

## Explicación del código

La primera variable declarada es fácil de explicar:

```
queen = [0 for c in range(8)]        #Row o f queen i n column c
```

Es el vector de números antes explicado. Contendrá una posible solución. Se irá rellenando de izquierda a derecha. Es decir, se asigna un valor a `queen[0]` (lo cual ya restringirá qué valores se pueden asignar a las siguientes), después a `queen[1]`, etc.

El resto del código es más difícil de comprender porque usa recursividad y una forma muy ingeniosa de almacenar qué casillas están amenazadas (y por tanto qué valores ya no se pueden usar para las reinas siguientes).

El truco es usar vectores de booleanos para "recordar" qué filas están ya amenazadas por las reinas colocadas hasta ese momento, y qué posiciones están amenazadas en diagonal.

```
rfree = [True for r in range(8)]     #Row rfree
```

El vector de las filas se entiende fácil. Al colocar una reina en la fila `r` (de *row*), se hace `rfree[r]=False`, con lo que el valor `r` ya no podrá volver a usarse.

El de las diagonales es más retorcido, y todo se basa en la siguiente propiedad: *para todas las casillas que estén en una misma **diagonal descendente**, se cumple que si sumas su número de fila y su número de columna, sale lo mismo*. Y para las **diagonales ascendentes** lo que sale lo mismo es restar su número de fila a su número de columna (si bien eso puede salir negativo, pero aún así se cumple). Puedes verificar esta propiedad tú mismo sobre este dibujo:

[image: Tablero numerado]

Entonces definimos:

```
dd = [True for i in range(15)]       #Diagonal i = c + rfree
```

Y lo que se hace es lo siguiente. Una vez la primera reina ha sido colocada, es decir, se ha asignado `queen[c]=r` (por ejemplo, `queen[0]=1` en la solución anterior), se hace `dd[c+r]=False` (en nuestro ejemplo, haría `dd[1]=False`). Eso marca que toda la diagonal descendente cuya suma sea `c+r`, está "amenazada". Un solo booleano controla la diagonal completa.

De forma análoga se tiene otro vector `du` (*diagonal up*) para guardar si la reina anterior amenaza en diagonal "hacia arriba" a la reina siguiente, o a cualquiera de las siguientes:

```
du = [True for i in range(15)]       #Diagonal i = c + 7 − r
```

En este caso, cada vez que se coloca una reina en la columna `c` fila `r`, se hace `du[c+7-r]=False`. Se suma 7 para garantizar que el resultado sea positivo.

El por qué estos vectores tienen 15 posiciones es porque en el caso extremo la operación `c+r` o `c+7-r` puede llegar a salir 14, y para poder acceder a la posición `[14]` del vector, éste necesita tener 15 posiciones. También, si cuentas todas las posibles diagonales descendentes (o ascendentes) que hay sobre el tablero, verás que son 15.

La función que resuelve todo es recursiva:

```
def solve(c):
    global solutions
```

El parámetro que recibe `c` representa la columna en la que tenemos que colocar una reina. Inicialmente será `0` y después se irá llamando a esta misma función para que coloque otra reina en la columna `c=1`, etc.

La función hace uso de variables globales para todo, si bien declara como global únicamente `solutions`, que es el contador de soluciones diferentes halladas hasta el momento. Las otras variables que he explicado antes también son globales, pero no es necesario declararlas como tales porque son vectores y lo que cambiamos es el valor que contiene el vector, pero no el vector a que apuntan. Es una "cosa rara" de python. El código sería más claro si se declararan también como globales, pues la función las usa de ese modo y espera que lo que se guarde en ellas siga ahí para cuando la función de nuevo se llama a sí misma recursivamente.

Después empieza por verificar el caso fácil. Si `c==8` es que ya hemos colocado las ocho reinas (pues no hay columna 8, la 7 es la última). En este caso se imprime la solución y se retorna:

```
    if c == 8:
        solutions += 1
        print(solutions, end = ": ")
        for r in range(8):
            print (queen[r] + 1 ,end = " " if r<7 else "\n")
```

**Nota** Fíjate que a la hora de imprimir suma 1 a los valores, de modo que en lugar de 0 a 7 está usando 1 a 8.

En caso contrario viene la parte recursiva.

```
    else:
        for r in range(8):
            if rfree[r] and dd[c + r] and du[ c+7-r]:
                queen[c] = r
                rfree[r] = dd[ c+r ] = du[ c+7-r ] = False
                solve(c+1)
                rfree[r] = dd[ c+r ] = du[ c+7-r ] = True
```

Básicamente viene a decir:

- Vamos a probar todas las filas (`r`) de una en una.
- Si la fila no está amenazada (porque los vectores `rfree` indican que no hay otra reina ya colocada en la misma fila, `dd` que no hay otra que me amenace en diagonal descendente y `du` que no hay otra que me amenace en diagonal ascendente), entonces:

  - Colocamos la reina en la fila `r`
  - Marcamos qué fila y diagonales amenaza (asignando `False` a los vectores apropiados)
  - Llamamos a `solve()`  para que resuelva para la siguiente columna
- Y una vez `solve()` haya retornado:

  - Quitamos la reina de esa fila, marcando de nuevo como no-amenazadas las correspondientes fila y diagonales (poniendo de nuevo a `True` los valores correspondientes)
  - Para de ese modo poder pasar a probar otra fila `r`

Observa que este algoritmo llevará también a muchos "callejones sin salida", que no se ven cuando lo ejecutas. Puede colocar una reina en una posición tal que impida colocar las que faltan. Pero de eso "se dará cuenta más adelante" cuando llegue el momento de colocar la reina 6 por ejemplo, y no haya ninguna fila donde ponerla. En ese caso el bucle `for r in range(8):` finaliza sin haber colocado la reina, por lo que la función no se llamará recursivamente a sí misma, sino que retornará, sin llegar al caso `c==8` que imprimiría la solución. El árbol de búsqueda se va "podando" solo.

Puedes hacer visibles todos los callejones sin salida si cambias la función de este modo:

```
def solve(c):
    global solutions
    stalled = True

    if c == 8:
        solutions += 1
        print(solutions, end = ": ")
        for r in range(8):
            print (queen[r] + 1 ,end = " " if r<7 else "\n")
    else:
        for r in range(8):
            if rfree[r] and dd[c + r] and du[ c+7-r]:
                queen[c] = r
                rfree[r] = dd[ c+r ] = du[ c+7-r ] = False
                solve(c+1)
                rfree[r] = dd[ c+r ] = du[ c+7-r ] = True
                stalled = False
        if stalled:
            print("Callejón sin salida con estado=",
               ",".join(str(q+1) for q in queen[:c]))
```

Esto imprime 664 callejones sin salida para llegar a las 92 soluciones.

Comment: Recordar solo que este algoritmo se basa en mover las reinas de una en una, para generar las soluciones e ir seleccionando las correctas. Hay otra posibilidad de resolverlo, haciendo saltos de caballo.

Comment: @Jakala ¿Cómo sería haciendo saltos de caballo? Entiendo que es algo así como partir de una posición y la siguiente reina colocarla a lo que sería un salto de caballo de la anterior? ¿O estaría permitido varios saltos? ¿Cómo generas exhaustivamente todas las soluciones posibles? Mira por ejemplo [en Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) todas las soluciones que hay. En ninguna de las soluciones se cumple que todas y cada una de las reinas estén a un salto de caballo de las vecinas.

Comment: exactamente no conozco el algoritmo, pero se basa en comprobar lo mismo que el de las reinas, pero priorizando elegir una casilla desplazada de la anterior reina y en movimiento de salto de caballo.